# I am getting an Error -error: The superclass 'xxxx' doesn't have a zero argument constructor

Tags: android, flutter, dart, constructor, localnotification

I am using flutter_local_notifications and This error is coming. The line 450 is

```
NotificationPlugin._() {
  init();
}
```

I am beginner so I have problem adding a constructor in the super class. How can I do so?
Also is there some other error as I am not sure if it is about adding a constructor only.

Answer (score 0):

You should check here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

You should call one of the superclass constructors.

Something like:

```
NotificationPlugin._(): super.namedConstructor('some argument value') {

  init();
}
```